# Any Idea/guess of how twitter saves its tweets in the database and updates it real-time

Tags: java, database, database-design, twitter, database-connection

I am making a twitter type of website (not as big as twitter:), but without using any twitter api), I have to decide what kind of database I should use and how to maintain it in consistent state.

The main problem: Suppose my website is a twitter clone(that will make my question easier to understand), if I have a user "A" has 100 friends and all his friends tweet something as the same time "A" logs in so at that point in time tweets will be fetched from database, but the database is being updated by his friends tweets => database is in inconsistent state

Q1> What would be the best solution to it? maintain 2 database, use multi-threading etc? Can anyone explain in detail.

Q2>What will be the best database for this particular usage.

Comment: Why would this cause the database to be in an inconsistent state?

Comment: The word you're looking for is Concurrency. Now go on, do some research. http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=database+concurrency.

Comment: I feel reason for inconsistency- At the same time people are updating and accessing the database

Comment: Ya Concurrency problem can you please elaborate, how is this accomplished in twitter.

Comment: There is no possibility of inconsistency unless multiple users are trying to update the *same* record, or if one user's update *depends* on the state of another user's record.  The scenario you describe is neither of these!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter uses a noSQL database called cassandra.

 Take a closer look here: [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

when somebody writes in db table - the whole table itself is not locked, so others can write there concurrently. And read it. So user A will receive all that others had time to wrote (if their transactions committed successfully). So there I don't see here any inconsistency